# how to open existing window in pyqt?

Tags: python

here is my code:

```
##########Main.py#############

class DialerWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Dialer):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def chatwindow(self):
        self.chatc=ChatcontactPage()
        self.chatc.show()
        self.hide()


class ChatcontactPage(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_chatcontacts):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
dialer1=DialerWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So this my main.py file .when i click on the chatwindow button window is open but its blank,but try same code execute for window its work.Whwn i use this same code i am getting blank window. so i need ur expertise on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the new window with `self.chatc.exec_()` instead of `self.chatc.show()`.

And because this will pause the execution of the `chatwindow` method, you probably want to perform the line `self.hide()` earlier.